# Typescript generic sorting array of objects with different types

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

I want to make a generic sort function for array containing objects of several interfaces in every type is possible (not 'any' just a lot of types). I searched the web for guides and got confused by different options that I couldn't use in my code. I would like to understand what is my knowledge gap and how to bridge it.

```
interface Customer {
    customerId?: number;
    companyName: string;
    creationDate?: Date;
}

  let customers: Customer[] = [
    {
      customerId: 2,
      companyName: "B",
      creationDate: new Date(2),
    },
    {
      customerId: 1,
      companyName: "a",
      creationDate: new Date(1),
    },
    {
      customerId: 3,
      companyName: "C",
      creationDate: new Date(3),
    }
  ]

  // That version works
  function sortDataByFieldV1(customers: Customer[], sortBy: string, sortDir: string): Customer[] {
    return customers.sort((obj1: Customer, obj2: Customer) => {
      const val1 = typeof(obj1[sortBy as keyof typeof obj1]) === 'string' 
        ? String(obj1[sortBy as keyof typeof obj1]).toLowerCase() 
        : obj1[sortBy as keyof typeof obj1];

      const val2 = typeof(obj2[sortBy as keyof typeof obj2]) === 'string' 
        ? String(obj2[sortBy as keyof typeof obj2]).toLowerCase() 
        : obj2[sortBy as keyof typeof obj2];

      let retVal = 0;
      if (val1 && val2) {
        if (val1 > val2) {
          retVal = 1;
        }

        if (val1 < val2) {
            retVal = -1;
        }
      }
      return sortDir === "desc" ? retVal * -1 : retVal;
    });
  }

  // That version does not work
  function sortDataByFieldV2<T, K extends keyof T>(customers: T[], sortBy: K, sortDir: string): T[] {
    return customers.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
      let retVal = 0;

      if (obj1[sortBy] > obj2[sortBy]) retVal = 1;
      if (obj1[sortBy] < obj2[sortBy]) retVal = -1;

      return sortDir === "desc" ? retVal * -1 : retVal;
    });
  }

// Usage example

// V1
const sortTableV1 = (sortingField: string, sortDir: string) => {
  customers = sortDataByFieldV1( 
    customers, sortingField, sortDir // sortingField raise TS error on sortDataByFieldV2
  ) as Customer[]
  return customers;
}

// V2
// const sortTableV2 = (sortingField: string, sortDir: string) => {
//   customers = sortDataByFieldV2( // V2
//     customers, sortingField, sortDir // sortingField raise TS error on sortDataByFieldV2
//   ) as Customer[]
//   return customers;
// }

console.log(sortTableV1("companyName", "asc"))
// console.log(sortTableV2("companyName", "asc"))
```

As requested, [minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbaZAbwChlzkEtcCoBJAEwH4AuZEdPAI2gG4yKCfAAc4IAJ4A5OATbYooAOb8KlKBDhhgOEABFNEVsn2R%20AXxICANhDCVq%20aJjYZsjqAG0AusgC8yDwFyUlVyKjdaRjYAJgAaIMERMSkZCDYAIgAhdPjQtQ0tHRM09ggAd2MDAApogEpcijMG4ISwh0iGNgBGZsS8UQlpWWR0uBzW-M1tPQM2EHLKyCqu%20oSmhJDQ8JpoKOQAZl6wpMHUjNRxvIR1KaLZ0oriqv3V1QtyL0tyAHpv5AAVAAWmmQADcnNNkGUcFAANaYAQwdAgBCFEDITAwsAmOCZcQAMWAECsDAAal0qtt3M40O1oN5YhisXi5GAFCBFIzMVBscAoKz2Ypai46Z4fJtyOowOgoOiqbRMAA6blgKpVHBcABWXRFEWgjI1muiup2UFqfgAfMQJkIQNgwXArF0-MgwOJhBAcDB1Vquh4VXjkHBMMhYRBxF7Xe7PTBkIaul5zb5k8gAOTyJSp5ATchMZAAZTZSh92v9zPEQZDYYjsbdHsj8cTitwABkcGVoKhgxAquac8g2PGyzzA8HQ%20HI3WY3HfV5%20DadPbQY7oi6p16S9Fh2BR1WJ7Xow2tdFE34U%20mixys-284XBZvt7vxzWo-XY4aT7Vmzg2x2oF3MB7Ps8nIQdj0fCsx2rSdD3fY85y%20UIbDsKVSUdF0AAYVFCYBYyqZcnWQAAyIiHSsOprRA5BcOQfDHWdK0CIoiUQNQ9D-C6bC8gsfsaLowiAB4yOY-tVDYqwXQAWk4-t3lCOSxNsGV0RVXQ%20TPfx0gYCBMAQdJkDzcTkAAKmQaSB2QcSuOQMxamwnifj%20IEQXBKBMEhBgcB09gcDsaE4URZFUUhVTNFxAkiRJUlogE-5GQAaWQCAAA9IBABg9xff4LUpUUaX%20BkmRHcQ2HirksTU-kMUvIU2AK8UEilZT7D1NzlSxNV4wNY8kytFjyGQyzbDQiT-CwxDVD4ocA3EHwrQ-CDTyMjjrPIKbfUW5AhIWmaluG9izJkiYmtlIreSgDSRm03T9MM-aJNM8y2CstY7IEHjfmQABVTA4EUFAUpkYQbEsT7yRIW17RVf44C4GxyRdKoVSUQliU6arBXKnlKoFJResolrTRDfxQrAcLUaiils1UeUnCxrQOQphh6cq5BPuRxnIoYSy4GAQCAXzJKoCgGE4xUiqwrxJnooEc0x1cU1vAEE65Ty8xQb%20GXPshuxodh%20HV38JGsRRrncY5Fm%20XNoVLWtT62la4mzpxKWueiqo2c16ISHtwQ8vp020cti72ZNzm0Z5vmUH%20QXoBFi6dGdyWIrRrW-nIOWQwV9wld9lXCepfhPp4yGcBsRUrBwRRjZ5GG4YgckqnSIR%20mSIYIByEZgz02pah9v5S-Lyvq71%20v3ebk4UgITvRhu3vLCAA)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB47bW).  (Note, this is asking for the code as text, not as a link, although a link would be a nice supplement).  Right now there are errors unrelated to your question, and a dependency on angular that seems to be unnecessary (sorting is probably independent of angular).  If you do [edit] to provide this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I added a link like you suggested and it seems to work. Also, thank you for introducing me  with the TS Playground.

Comment: When you say "it seems to work", what do you mean? And what is not working about your original code?  Could you clarify the problem if there is one, or remove the question if there isn't one?

Comment: @jcalz As I am new to programming, I want to use good practices. The first version works well, but it is complicated and would probably be more difficult to maintain than the second version that doesn't work. I wish to understand how to make the second version work because I think something in my understanding of typescript is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what “doesn’t work”. That’s not a sufficient description of the problem (see the guidelines for what makes a [mre], specifically the “reproducible” part).